# Sodium borohydride and lithium aluminium hydride

Tags: redox

Both sodium borohydride and lithium aluminium hydride are common reducing agents in organic chemistry. Then can these reducing agents be applied in inorganic chemistry? I mean, for example, reducing acidified potassium dichromate, an inorganic compound.

Comment: NaBH4 and LiAlH4 are themselves both inorganic compounds, so yes, they can react with inorganic compounds.

Answer (score 7):

In the case of sodium borohydride (which is more compatible with aqueous solutions), applications are known involving metal reduction. A few examples:

**Precious metal recovery/recycle**

Silver and platinum group metals are reducible from water-soluble salts using sodium borohydride. Initially the method was used for recovering silver from thiosulfate solutions used for photographic fixing; the application has now spread to recovery of "most precious metals". See [Medding and Lander[1]](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-025392-3.50007-7).

**Wastewater treatment/Metal recovery**

Sodium borohydride reduction can be used to remove certain heavy metals from wastewater, including copper. See [Sithole et al. [2]](https://doi.org/10.1088/1755-1315/120/1/012022).

**Ceramic nanomaterials**

The reduction of cobalt chloride solution with sodium borohydride under controlled conditions yields $\ce{Co2B}$ powder with particle sizes 20-100 nm. See [Jianming et al.[3]](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-386X(96)00086-2).

**References**

1. G.L. Medding, J.A. Lander,
   "Applications for sodium borohtdride in precious metal recovery and recycle", Editor(s): E.D. Zysk,
   *Precious Metals 1981*, Pergamon, 1982, Pages 3-10,
   ISBN 9780080253923,
   https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-025392-3.50007-7.
2. N T Sithole, F Ntuli and T Mashifana (2018). "The Removal of Cu (II) from Aqueous Solution using Sodium Borohydride as a Reducing Agent". *IOP Conf. Ser.: Earth Environ. Sci.* **120** 012022.
   DOI 10.1088/1755-1315/120/1/012022.
3. Jianming Lu, D.B. Dreisinger, W.C. Cooper (1997). "Cobalt precipitation by reduction with sodium borohydride",
   *Hydrometallurgy* **45**(3), 305-322,
   ISSN 0304-386X,
   https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-386X(96)00086-2.